# Liferay: get PortletId and Plid from init(PortletConfig) [i.e, no request object, just PortletConfig]

Tags: java, liferay, portlet, init

I would like to get both values, and since init(Portletconfig) is executed when loading the portlet, I don't see any doubt about whether this values should be available.

For portletId I tried

```
String portletId = ((PortletConfigImpl) portletConfig).getPortletId();
```

but it seems I can't. Guess it is because the impl is in another jar not meant to be accessed from portlets

By the way, my main goal is to get to pass both params to another non-request context so I can do

```
final PortletPreferences prefs = PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getLayoutPortletSetup(LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getLayout(plid), portletId);
```

to read portlet's prefs in real time. If there is any other way to indicate that from init(), like getting the whole preferences it would be enough

**EDIT:** I found a different approach, and opened a new question with slightly changes
 [Liferay: get PortletID and companyID from init()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322904/liferay-get-portletid-and-companyid-from-init)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So... If I understand it right, your goal is to read out portlet preferences inside the init method of your Portlet class.

According to the API, the `PortletPreferences` object can be retrieved from a `PortletRequest` instance, which is available in both `doView()` and `processAction()` classes. E.g.:

```
public void doView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) throws PortletException, IOException {
    String name = request.getPreferences().getValue("name", null);

    Writer writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.write("Hello, "+name+"!");
}
```

It is important to note that in Liferay, portlet preferences by default only exist within the scope of a page, or, in Liferay terms, a `Layout`, which is identified by a `plid`, short-hand for page layout id.

Concerning your `init()` method, the portlet API dictates that this method should be called "before the first portlet request is handled". In Liferay, a new instance (and only ONE instance) of your portlet class is created at **deploy time**, not when you add a portlet on a page. After instantiation, the portal container will call the `init()` method of the portlet class.

Conclusion: it doesn't make sense at all to retrieve portlet preferences in the `init()` method of your portlet class, because at that point the portlet doesn't have any context (read: `Layout`) from which it should retrieve the preferences.

Comment: So then if you want to say validate preferences from portlet.xml just for first time you need to do it every request?

Comment: What do you mean by "validate"? You mean you have configured portlet preferences in `portlet.xml` and you want to validate those?

Comment: For instance. An operation I would like to do just when portlet is initialited and not per any request

Comment: It's simply impossible to do this kind of checking in the `init()` method, because you you're not in the right context at that point.

Comment: seconding this. It's not possible! Also, when you read portlet preferences in init(), this implies that you want to store them in member variables, which is (in 98% of cases I see) the wrong place. Most likely there will ever only be one portlet object in the whole system, and the whole context is to be carried in through the request/response objects (like it used to be with servlets). I can only guess this is done for preliminary optimization. If you're up to that: Measure where optimization makes sense. You'll see that accessing the portlet preferences is not the bottleneck, so why bother?

Comment: Sorry I forgot an important thing: the portlet is in config panel, so maybe there is a kinf of static plid for it

Comment: I found a solution but I still need help. I approved that question but I added a new one slightly different with the changed logic, is very simple, could you help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322904/liferay-get-portletid-and-companyid-from-init

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get configuration of portlet initialization, then you can override the `init(PortletConfig config)` methode from `GenericPortlet`

> public class MyLiferayTestPortlet extends MVCPortlet {
>
> ```
>   @Override
>   public void init(PortletConfig config) throws PortletException {
>     System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ init");
>     super.init(config);
>     Enumeration<String> parameterNames = config.getInitParameterNames();
>     while(parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
>         String name = parameterNames.nextElement();
>         System.out.println("Parameter: " + name + " = " + config.getInitParameter(name));
>     }
>     System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /init");
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: That is what i am doing (the init() in the question is for init (Portletconfig) that is why I said just Portletconfig no request object.But how can I retrieve PortletId and PlId from it?

Comment: You cannot get `plid` because the init methode will be run independed from Layout. For example in my portlet the init methode is runnig by deployment, without that this portlet is placing at any page.

Comment: Once that you can hold is all pages (plids) where the portlet is placed.

Comment: but isnt init called when portlet is placed or instantiated in any page? it should be possible to get WHERE is being placed

Comment: The `init` will be call when the portlet (not portlet instance) is called first time - by portal start, by redeploy of portlet, when the portlet was destroyd by garbage collector. See the portlet specification (JSR 168) for more information.

And Yes, you can get the position of all portlet instances. If you need this, than create another question and describe what do you want to arrive at last.

Comment: But the question is if I can get the position somehow of the current instance I am deploying. If you say that i can retrieve all layouts that are placed, that means that is possible to get the current plid, the problem is how to identify which of them is the current

Comment: What do you mean with "current plid"? You cannot deploy only one instance of portlet, you deploy a portlet (container), and the instances of this portlet can be placed at various Layouts.

Comment: Why you cannot use the "doView(...)" methode?

Comment: because i need to pass this info into a background job and i would like to do it in init time and not some mechanism for communicatng with it and checking it has its parameters for every request

Comment: In backgroud job you have no "current plids".

Comment: but you can need associated preferences for the portlet it runs, so you have to pass this

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean :(

Comment: I meant that for retrieving preferences I need plid. But no worry, I ended up using a mix of all solutions and changing it a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just put the preferences retrieval code to the render phase, and make a flag when the preferences have been validated? This way you only need to do it once.

For example, in the controller you have have a static field

```
private static boolean checked = false;
```

And then in the render phase, you check

```
if(!checked) {
//validate preferences
checked = true;
}
```

Comment: because I am learning Liferay and I want to know if i am missing something and it could be done from an init stage where is supposed to be placed this kind of init actions.

Comment: Yes I understand. But getting plid and portletId seems to be impossible to retrieve in init(), so this was just my suggestion of how to solve your problem.

Comment: So far, it is possible if you have only one company and portlet is in special type like Control Panel.